# \cite doesn't work

Tags: citing, natbib, apa-style

If I use `\citeA{Rannenberg}` it works, but with `\cite{Rannenberg}` I get the error:

```
("C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\BA Test\chapters/test.tex"
Kapitel 1.

Class scrbook Warning: \float@addtolists detected!
(scrbook)              You should use the features of package `tocbasic'
(scrbook)              instead of \float@addtolists.
(scrbook)              Support for \float@addtolists may be removed from
(scrbook)              `scrbook' soon .

Overfull \vbox (1.94844pt too high) has occurred while \output is active
[1]
Runaway argument?
]{Rannenberg} 
! Paragraph ended before \@citex was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.65 
?
```

Hear my example:

```
\usepackage{natbib} 
\usepackage[nosectionbib]{apacite} 
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{bib/testbib}
@book{Rannenberg,
 author = {Rannenberg, Kai},
 year = {2002},
 title = {{S}icherheit bei {M}obile {B}anking},
 address = {Frankfurt am Main},
 urldate = {01.03.2011},
 institution = {{Fachbereich Wirtschaftswissenschaften Johann Wolfgang Goethe-Universit{\"a}t Frankfurt am Main}}
}
```

My Target is to get the follow results: (Rannenberg, 2002: 38). 38 is the pagenumber.

Comment: Please add a working example. The one you added isn't complete.

Answer (score 17):

I had the same error. I just deleted the package `\usepackage{cite}` from the main TeX file and `\cite{reference}` did work!

You can use:

```
\cite[p.~38]{Rannenberg}
```

in order to get the page number on the reference. I hope this can help.

Comment: Could you explain how your answer addresses the OP's issues? The OP's example shows the `natbib` and `apacite` packages being loaded, but there's no mention of the `cite` package being loaded.

Comment: It might not be related to the OP question. But this question is the first result on Google for `! Paragraph ended before \@citex was complete.` and for me too removing `\usepackage{cite}` from the Latex preamble fixed the issue.

Answer (score 5):

please provide full working examples and not only fragments which didn't really show what you exactly did. If I change the order of `natbib` and `apacity` I have no problem with this example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[nosectionbib]{apacite} 
\usepackage{natbib} 
\begin{filecontents}{testbib.bib}
@book{Rannenberg,
 author = {Rannenberg, Kai},
 year = {2002},
 title = {{S}icherheit bei {M}obile {B}anking},
 address = {Frankfurt am Main},
 urldate = {01.03.2011},
 institution = {{Fachbereich Wirtschaftswissenschaften Johann Wolfgang Goethe-Universit{\"a}t Frankfurt am Main}}
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}

foo~\cite[38]{Rannenberg}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{testbib}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Norbert and Thorsten: Thanks for your answer. Sorry, but it doesn't work by me. Could I send you my whole document? I'm new Latex user and have no idea, what you mean with full working example. Thanks

Comment: @CSI: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem, when using similar case like `\cite{Rannenberg}`, after I look carefully to the content of `.tex`, I found that I missed a "}" when using `\cite{}`, so I just use `\cite{Rannenberg`   without a `}` in the end.

I hope this may be helpful to some one here.